# SSAS 2008 Basics : Tutorial

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm looking for pointers to a tutorials for SSAS 2008 which also covers learning MDX queries ?

Comment: use this Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456661/sample-mdx-queries/18298672#18298672

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend starting with the [books online tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170208.aspx) for Analysis Services and the [books online tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144785.aspx) for MDX.  You can't get much better help for free.

The [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 MDX Step by Step](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=12914&locale=en-us) is the best book I've read regarding learning MDX queries when you are just starting out.  It was about as good as SQL Queries for Mere Mortals but for MDX.

The [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Step by Step](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626200) is the best book I've read regarding learning how to build a cube from scratch.  I went through building my first cube with the samples and then built a cube on my real company data following the same steps.  This book won't help teach you MDX, though.

I also found the [Microsoft Data Warehouse Toolkit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471267155) useful from a conceptual level, but I didn't find it to be very useful from a practical level.  The [Applied Microsoft Analysis Services 2005 and Microsoft Business Intelligence Platform](http://www.prologika.com/Books/0976635305/Book.aspx) book was very useful for digging into the nuts and bolts at a level that exceeded the Step by Step books and it has a very good series of chapters on MDX programming that helped me move beyond the MDX Step by Step book.

Googling MDX tutorial will give you some basic queries, but I found I couldn't go beyond the basics without hitting the books.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I think I had got a lot.

Comment: I would not recommend "Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Anaylsis Services" by Melomed et al.     
Very dry and overwhelming levels of detail in earlier chapters.  i.e. Describing DDL used inside various objects when really you need to get to grips with the fundamentals of what things are.

Answer (score 5):

I have previously offered my own careful explanation of how OLAP works and how to learn MDX, and they have been welcomed.
http://sites.google.com/site/merlinmags/

Comment: I had a look at your documents. I applaud your effort to contribute to the community but a couple of pages covering OLAP doesn't really help with learning SSAS. Thanks again though. +1

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for a Functional book i thing this book help you.

practical mdx queries for Microsoft SQL server Analysis Service.

The book is published by Art Tennick.

There are more than 300 such applications.

[http://www.amazon.com/Practical-MDX-Queries-Microsoft-ebook/dp/B003QP3XGY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003QP3XGY)

http://books.google.com/books/about/Practical_MDX_Queries_For_Microsoft_SQL.html?id=UqHSphxb0_YC

http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8381527-practical-mdx-queries

Answer (score 0):

Your list is not complete without this beautiful book full of practical and theoretical advice: 
[http://www.amazon.com/Expert-Development-Microsoft-Analysis-Services/dp/1847197221](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847197221)